# Is there a way to get the code from "github.mit.edu"?

Tags: scrnaseq, sequence-analysis

everyone. 
I am a postdoc who just begins to analyze single-cell RNA-seq data.
Nowadays, I found a really interesting paper (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.celrep.2018.10.047, PMID: 30404002). So, I decided to study bioinformatics by drawing the same graphs presented in the paper during the corona outbreak season. However, it was turned out that I can't get any access to the website in which code is deposited. Here is the address for the website.

Do you guys know how to get the code to learn bioinformatics and make graphs?

Thank you.

Comment: Follow the Bioconductor single-cell workflow: https://osca.bioconductor.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very strange that they put their code somewhere cannot be easily accessed. If they just put it under a normal Github repo, there would not be such a problem. One way to get the code is simply to email the corresponding author. People are usually responsive if you are interested in their work.

Comment: Thank you. I just sent the e-mail to PI. I hope to get the code information.

Comment: It is not uncommon for Institutions to set-up their own private github / gitlab instances to have more control over their code and what they do with it. Furthermore, it is quite likely that this was a private repo and someone forgot to change it to public. It happens. As the saying goes, never attribute to malice what can be explained by incompetence (or absent-mindedness) :)